# How to describe "working steadily and slowly is treated as stubborn"

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

It is not uncommon that those who prefer to work or learn in a solid and therefore usually slow way are being called as stubborn, and those in a fast-pacing but non-solid way as smart. I wonder how you would express such phenomenon? Does English have some words and/or fixed phrases for this purpose? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a description of *the tortoise and the hare*.  The 'problem', from your point of view, is that the tortoise won the race, and so showed the superiority of working slowly but doggedly.

Answer (score 1):

Would 'A rolling stone catches no moss' suffice for you? An accepted interpretation for the saying is that mobility prevents stagnation and seems to be apt for the situation that you describe.

If you want to praise people who are meticulous, there is 'Slow and steady wins the race'.

Comment: Thanks! Is there some saying that sarcastically describe the phenomenon? Because I don't agree with such phenomenon.

Comment: Rolling stone **s gather** no moss.

Comment: -1 for the "rolling stone" adage, which has no connection with OP's context (the other one is apposite, though).

Comment: -1 for the same reason as @FumbleFingers - "A rolling stone gathers no moss" pertains to a quite different situation.

Answer (score 1):

Fast and non-solid may be called **error-prone**.

Comment: Thanks! It takes one a strong mind to stick to his own principle despite others' opinions.

Comment: Slow and non-solid may also be called error-prone. "Error-prone" tells us nothing about speed or cause. Only about susceptibility to errors.

Answer (score 1):

"[Stolid](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stolid)" comes to mind as a word for the first type of person, though it doesn't apply to  work per se, more attitude. Also "[phlegmatic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/phlegmatic)".

Answer (score 1):

I think *[systematic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/systematic)*, "methodical, regular and orderly" and *[intuitive](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intuitive)*, "spontaneous, without requiring conscious thought" are perhaps more appropriate than *stubborn* and *smart*.

Note, *[stolid](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stolid)* connotes stupid, and *[phlegmatic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/phlegmatic)* connotes both *sluggish* and *unemotional*, rather than suggesting the "solid and slow way" you mention in the question.

The term *[dianoetic](http://poets.notredame.ac.jp/cgi-bin/wn?cmd=wn&word=dianoetic)* has sense "proceeding to a conclusion by reason or argument rather than intuition" in some dictionaries, and as [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=dianoetic) notes, is supposed to be the word from which L. Ron Hubbard coined *dianetics*, ca. 1950.  Other than that it's a fine but obscure word to express use of systematic instead of intuitional methods.